# Why does columns cause emergency stop in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, columns

I am working on a Beamer presentation with columns. When I run:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
 \frametitle{Example}
 \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{0.415\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale = .25]{mosaic.pdf}
 \end{figure}
 \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.415\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}
ods select MosaicPlot;
proc freq data = mosaic;
 table party*sex/
 plots = mosaic;
 weight count;
run;
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

it runs fine. But when I run the very similar:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Strip chart - example}
    \begin{columns}
     \begin{column}{0.425\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale = .35]{strip.pdf}
 \end{figure}
 \end{column}
 \begin{column}{0.425\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}
title "Salary by division, rookies";
 proc sgplot data = sashelp.baseball;
  scatter x = salary y = div;
  where yrmajor le 1;
 run;
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

it causes:

Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 103
.

```
Overfull \hbox (46.10982pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 103--106
[][]\T1/phv/m/n/10.95 stlistingolumnolumns
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> _temp.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

which I don't understand at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `fragile` in the second one.

Since you have verbatim text in both frames (listings of code), both frames require the `fragile` option. The first has it:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
```

so all is well. The second lacks it:

```
\begin{frame}
```

so it ends in tears :(.